# Menú dinámico multi nivel

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, mysqli

Quiero hacer un menú dinámico que :

> Muestre sus respectivos `<li>`sin mostrar sus hijos.

Al hacer `hover`en cualquier `<li>`**padre** muestre el `<ul> + <li> hijos`

> Obteniendo los datos `$var` o `strings` traidos de una `base de datos`

---

*En la base de datos, tengo:*

*Una tabla para "**marcas**" y una tabla para "**productos**"*
Las cuales utilizo para el filtrado de búsqueda por marcas o por `%LIKE`.

```
<li>Placas de video</li>
```

Primer `click/hover` >  MSI / GEFORCE etc..

Segundo`click` >> lleva a una busqueda con `LIKE %msi%` (sin `hover`ya que no se necesita mostrar nada)

**Tabla `marcas`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `marcas` (
 `id_marca` int(50) NOT NULL,
 `marca` varchar(50) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `marcas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_marca`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_marca` (`id_marca`);
```

**Tabla `productos`:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `productos` (
   `id_producto` int(50) NOT NULL,
   `codigo_p` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `id_marca` int(50) NOT NULL,
   `nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `presentacion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `precio` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `iva` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.21,
   `ivatotal` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `preciototal` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `tags` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `foto` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `descripcion` text NOT NULL,
   `stock` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Si'
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

//  Indices de la tabla `productos`

 ALTER TABLE `productos`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_producto`),
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_producto` (`id_producto`),
   ADD KEY `codigo_p` (`codigo_p`),
   ADD KEY `ps_marcas` (`id_marca`),
   ADD KEY `ps_tags` (`tags`);
 ---
 ALTER TABLE `productos`
   MODIFY `id_producto` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=0;

 // Exportado con PHPMYADMIN (xampp/localhost)
```

> ¿Cual seria la mejor forma de elaborar el menu multinivel con datos de la BD utilizando PHP?

---

**Aclaración:**

Estos **"padres"** e **"hijos"** tienen vinculos con **"productos"**. Los cuales se mostraron al hacer click o ingresar en *categoria* o *subcategoria*

Estoy utilizando **bootstrap** asi que el `HTML` para el/los items seran:

```
<li class="nav-item">
```

Comment: No termina de quedarme claro cuál es el problema que quieres resolver: ¿quieres cambiar la base de datos? ¿Quieres leer datos para luego mostrarlos? ¿Quieres crear un menú? . Quizás se entendería mejor si añadieses más información sobre las tablas que tienes y su relación, así como lo que hayas intentado y con que problemas/dificultades te estés encontrando.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya edite mi pregunta. Agregue las 2 tablas por el momento que creo necesarias para la creación del menu. (Es posible que necesite re-estrucutrarlo). El menu quiero que se genere con datos de la `base de datos`

Comment: Por favor enfoca un poco tu pregunta a un problema en especifico. Concuerdo con @AlvaroMontoro no me queda claro que quieres exactamente ya que leo tu pregunta y es como ver 3 preguntas en 1

Comment: @Huskie ya edite mi pregunta. Hazme saber si todavía no queda claro.

Comment: Definitivamente ahora si quedó clara @Juan Dame unos minutos y te coloco mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias @Huskie por brindar ayuda, estoy hace meses elaborando una tienda virtual y a veces estoy por dejar, ya que muchas cosas me resultan dificiles ^^ Espero la respuesta y verificare si resuelve la pregunta.

Comment: Edito: Item - Subitem , (siempre los datos traidos de BD)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72329/discussion-between-huskie-and-juan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear una tabla llamada **"menu"** con la siguiente estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `menu_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_padre` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `estatus` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

Luego insertamos algunos valores de ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO `menu` (`menu_id`, `menu_nombre`, `id_padre`, `link`, `estatus`) VALUES
(1, 'Pendrive', 0, '#', '1'),
(2, 'Categoria2', 0, '#', '1'),
(3, 'Categoria3', 0, '#', '1'),
(4, 'Kingston', 1, 'pendrives/kingston', '1'),
(5, 'marca1', 1, 'pendrives/marca1', '1'),
(6, 'marca2', 1, 'pendrives/marca2', '1'),
(7, 'marca3', 1, 'pendrives/marca3', '0'),
(8, 'marcax', 2, 'categoria2/marcax', '1'),
(9, 'marcab', 3, 'categoria3/marcab', '1'),
(10, 'marcag', 3, 'categoria3/marcag', '1'),
(11, '8GB', 3, 'pendrives/kingston/8gb', '1'),
```

Explico uno a uno los campos de la tabla:

**menu_id:** Es un autoincremental que diferenciará cada elemento de la tabla menú

**menu_nombre:** Es el nombre que el usuario verá dentro del menú. Ejemplo: Pendrive->Kingston->8GB (tanto pendrive como kingston y 8GB son los nombres que mostrará el menú multinivel)

**id_padre:** Es la clave para que el menú se haga dinámico. Este campo indicará si el registro en cuestión es "hijo" o no de algún otro registro presente en la tabla menú.

**A)** Por defecto para mostrar los elementos que conforman la raíz del menú (el nivel 1) se debe colocar el id_padre en "0"

**B)** Si tenemos por ejemplo el registro `(4, 'Kingston', 1, 'pendrives/kingston', '1'),` vemos que el parent_id es "1" esto quiere decir que "Kingston" es hijo de "Pendrive" cuyo parent_id es justamente "1". Igualmente para el resto de la tabla

**link:** Es la dirección del formulario o de la "vista" que mostrarás cuando el usuario de click dentro del menú en algún nombre en especifico.

**estatus:** Tendrá valor "0" o "1". Si está inactivo será "0" (no lo ve el usuario por algún propósito en particular) si está activo (lo puede ver el usuario) es "1"

Con respecto al php asociado a crear el menú dinámicamente tenemos lo siguiente:

```
function crear_menu($id_padre) 
{ 
// En esta línea va la conexión a tu base de datos, es decir, la cadena de conexión.
$menu = ""; // Vaciamos la variable menú 
$consulta = " SELECT * FROM menu where estatus='1' and id_padre=$id_padre"; 
$resultado=mysqli_query($con,$consulta); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{ 
$menu .="<li><a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['menu_nombre']."</a>"; 

$menu .= "<ul>".crear_menu($row['menu_id'])."</ul>"; //LLamada recursiva para generar todos los niveles del menú 

$menu .= "</li>"; 

} 

return $menu; 
}
```

La función anterior es para generar el menú dinámicamente con un método recursivo con base al id_padre. Esta función la agregas en donde tengas tus otras funciones y sencillamente la llamas en la vista donde quieras generar el menú de la siguiente forma:

```
<ul>
   <?php echo crear_menu(0); ?> 
</ul>
```

**Nota:** Siempre pasamos parametro "0" a la función para que esta genere el menú desde el primer nivel o la base que son aquellos elementos que no poseen padres o se pueden llamar también elementos raíz.

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72329/discussion-between-huskie-and-juan) @huskie

Answer (score 0):

Tuve curiosidad si era existia ya que nunca había visto ese comportamiento. Pense de en hacerlo pero ya [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h) lo tenia hecho asi que lo publico para ti:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Esto lo que hace es aplicarle la posicion relativa a los hijos de los hijos de los dropdown y moverlos un 100% a la izquierda para que no se solapen. El jquery hacer un toggle sobre si mostrar/ocultar el ul nieto. Recuerda que tienes que agregar las clases css que hay explicitas para que te funcione.

Comment: Gracias @Einer , cuando solucione el tema de la base de datos, armare la estructura con ese código.