# Menú dinámico: ¿Cómo acceder a enlaces en subcategorías?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una tienda en la que las subcategorías de los productos se originan según se ingresen subcategorías en la base de datos y se muestran en la propia tienda en un menú lateral. Entonces lo que quiero hacer es que al pinchar sobre esas subcategorías se me muestren sólo los productos de dicha subcategoría.

De momento he creado un código que me muestra la url que quiero. Por ejemplo, si pincho en la subcategoría "Guitarras", la url es:

```
cuerda.php?subcategoria=Guitarras
```

He Aquí el código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
<section class="subcategorias col-xs-2" style=" background: red">
    <ul>
        <?php
            $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario_BD, $contrasena_BD, $basedatos) or
                die("Problemas con la conexión");
            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

            $consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT subcategoria FROM producto WHERE categoria = 'cuerda'";
            $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
            $cantidad_registros = mysqli_num_rows($respuesta);

            while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
                echo "<li><a href='cuerda.php?subcategoria=".$fila["subcategoria"]."'>".$fila["subcategoria"]."</a></li>";

            }

            mysqli_close($conexion);
        ?>
    </ul>   
</section>
```

Dejo el código entero de la página aquí:

https://textsave.de/text/XOfWJUOquCpraJjx

Comment: Hola Katze, Bienvenido(a) a StackOverflow. Te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para observar mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla! También te invito a revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo!

Comment: He respondido a una pregunta muy similar que espero pueda ayudarte: [Menú dinámico multinivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134211/men%c3%ba-din%c3%a1mico-multi-nivel/134321#134321)

Answer (score 1):

A ver... primero tienes que acostumbrarte a usar [mysqli->prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) y poner placeholders en tu query en vez de meter directamente texto concatenado. Esto último abre la puerta a inyecciones SQL.

Dicho esto, el script que muestras debiera ser escrito como:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario_BD, $contrasena_BD, $basedatos);

$consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT subcategoria FROM producto WHERE categoria = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);

/* acá haces bind del parámetro real */
$stmt->bind_param("s", 'cuerda');

/* ejecutas la query */
$stmt->execute();

$respuesta = $stmt->get_result();
$cantidad_registros = $stmt->affected_rows;

while($fila = $respuesta->fetch_array(\MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<li><a href='cuerda.php?subcategoria=".$fila["subcategoria"]."'>".$fila["subcategoria"]."</a></li>";
}

/* liberas el statement */
$stmt->close();


/* liberas la connexion */
$mysqli->close();
```

Esto pudiera parecer un intro innecesario, pero resulta que la respuesta a tu pregunta se maneja exactamente igual. Cuando pinchas en `cuerda.php?subcategoria=.$fila["subcategoria"].`  tu script `cuerda.php` debiera ser:

```
$subcategoria = $_GET['subcategoria'];

$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario_BD, $contrasena_BD, $basedatos);

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE subcategoria = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $subcategoria);
```

pausa: si prefieres, puedes hacer más eficiente la consulta poniendo:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE subcategoria = ? and categoria=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $subcategoria,'cuerda');
```

Seguimos:

```
/* ejecutas la query */
$stmt->execute();

$respuesta = $stmt->get_result();
$cantidad_registros = $stmt->affected_rows;

while($fila = $respuesta->fetch_array(\MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ...acá iteras sobre los productos de la subcategoría escribiendo en pantalla lo que necesitas
}

/* liberas el statement */
$stmt->close();


/* liberas la connexion */
$mysqli->close();
```

Dicho esto, creo que es innecesario tener un script `cuerdas.php` específicamente para la categoría cuerdas... Sería más eficiente manejar todas las categorías en un solo script y que la categoría se pase mediante un parámetro igual como ahora vas a pasar la subcategoría.

Comment: Uff, eso no lo domino prácticamente nada todavía. No entiendo casi nada de ese código. Se agradece, pero me he quedado igual que antes.